# ResultSet to List<Product> and List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, list, resultset

Hi today i need help to get data from a resultSet to my List. It works fine with my List> but when i try to recode it to my List it returns null

In CMD I try to Print it using System.out

This is what it looks like in my List< Map< String, String >>

```
I/System.out(15168): connectcom.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@31e2b7ce
I/System.out(15168): rs = com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@18c765fc
I/System.out(15168): stmt = com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@8dd36ef
I/System.out(15168): else
I/System.out(15168): while
I/System.out(15168): 1
I/System.out(15168): while
I/System.out(15168): 2
I/System.out(15168): while
I/System.out(15168): 3
I/System.out(15168): while
I/System.out(15168): 4
```

and This is the System.out in my List < Product >

```
I/System.out(16051): DID try
I/System.out(16051): connectcom.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@31e2b7ce
I/System.out(16051): query = select * from countries
I/System.out(16051): rs = com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@18c765fc
I/System.out(16051): stmt = com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@8dd36ef
I/System.out(16051): else
I/System.out(16051): ID: null
```

as you can see it return null while in Map it returns the ID: 1234

Here is the code for List< Map< String, String >>

```
package com.mackhielan.firebasecloudmessaging;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by McKhee on Nov 22 2017.
 */

public class GetData {
    Connection connect;
    String ConnectionResult = "";
    Boolean isSuccess= false;

    public List<Map<String, String>> getData() {
        List<Map<String,String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

            try {
                ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                connect = connectionHelper.connections();
                System.out.println("connect" + connect);
                if(connect == null){
                    ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access";
                    System.out.println("if");
                    System.out.println("CR = " + ConnectionResult);
                }
                else{
                    String query = "select * from countries";
                    Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    System.out.println("rs = " + rs);
                    System.out.println("stmt = " + stmt);
                    System.out.println("else");

                    while(rs.next()) {
                        Map<String,String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        datanum.put("ID", rs.getString("CountryId"));//datanum.put("somethingLikeID", rs.getString("yourColumnNameOne"));
                        datanum.put("Country", rs.getString("CountryName"));//datanum.put("somethingLikeName", rs.getString("yourColumnNameTwo"));
                        datanum.put("Capital", rs.getString("CapitalCity"));//datanum.put("somethingLikeAddress", rs.getString("yourColumnNameThree"));
                        data.add(datanum);
                        System.out.println("while");
                        System.out.println(rs.getString("CountryId"));
                    }

                    ConnectionResult = "Successful";
                    isSuccess=true;
                    connect.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
                System.out.println(ConnectionResult);
            }
            return data;
    }
}
```

And for the List < Product >

```
package com.mackhielan.firebasecloudmessaging;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by McKhee on Nov 27 2017.
 */

public class GetDataList {
    Connection connect;
    String ConnectionResult = "";
    Boolean isSuccess= false;

    public List<Product> getListProduct() {
        Product product = null;
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            System.out.println("DID try");
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = connectionHelper.connections();

            System.out.println("connect" + connect);
            if(connect == null){
                ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access";
                System.out.println("if");
                System.out.println("CR = " + ConnectionResult);
            }
            else{
                String query = "select * from countries";
                Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println("query = " + query);
                System.out.println("rs = " + rs.toString());
                System.out.println("stmt = " + stmt.toString());
                System.out.println("else");
                System.out.print("ID: ");
                System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("CountryId"));
                while(rs.next()) {
                    product = new Product(rs.getInt(0), rs.getString(1),  rs.getString(2));
                    productList.add(product);

                }

                ConnectionResult = "Successful";
                isSuccess=true;
                connect.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(ConnectionResult);
        }
        return productList;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mackhielan.firebasecloudmessaging;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView LV_Data;
    SimpleAdapter AD;
    private ListProductAdapter adapter;
    private List<Product> mProductList;
    private GetDataList gdl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LV_Data = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LV_Data);
        gdl = new GetDataList();

        try {
            mProductList = gdl.getListProduct();
            adapter = new ListProductAdapter(this, mProductList);
            LV_Data.setAdapter(AD);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Here", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

### Any ideas why is it that it returns NULL my List < Product >????

Just comment if somethings missing that is vital to my code and if i have it i will add it ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the below value coming as NULL

```
I/System.out(16051): ID: null
```

because  you have to print this line inside **while** block in your GetDataList class

```
 //System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("CountryId"));
 while(rs.next()) {
       System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("CountryId"));
```

Use labels for retrieving column values instead of column order like your other class GetData.As in GetData class it worked as per you so definitely it will work in GetDataList class as well. But still if you have to use column order to retrieve value from Resultset then make sure your column orders are correct .Your code should run like below

```
    while(rs.next()) {
         product = new Product(rs.getString("CountryId"), rs.getString("CountryName"),  rs.getString("CapitalCity"));
         productList.add(product);
}
```